# Sound shortened in PyGame

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I'm using Ubuntu 10.4 and learning PyGame following the tutorial 'Pummel the chimp and win $$$'.

I made two '.wav' files, but when i try to play them, i get a strange noise just like a thud, very short.

I don't get any error message. Why doesn't this work as expected?

```
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.init()
(6, 0)
>>> def load_sound(name):
    class NoneSound(object):
        def play(self): pass
    if not pygame.mixer:
        return NoneSound()
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(fullname)
    except pygame.error, message:
        print 'Cannot load sound:', name
        raise SystemExit, message
    return sound

>>> whiff_sound = load_sound('whiff.wav')
>>> whiff_sound.play()
<Channel object at 0xb772f1c0>
>>>
```

Comment: Have you played the .wav files with a standalone audio player?

Comment: You should upload and provide a link to one of those wav you have problems with. Also, the code should be a plain Python script, not the output of an interactive console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with a sound, I opened my sound in a program called WavePad Sound Editor and re-saved the file as a .wav and set the sample rate to 22050 Hz and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was that this sounds like a problem with sampling frequency. Whenever the mixer is initiated its default values are:

> pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050,
>   size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096):
>   return None

If frequency=22050, being the sampling frequency, is different from the sampling frequency of your sound, this could cause problems (essentially speeding up or slowing down the playback of the sound).

However, the documentation for pygame.mixer.Sound reads:

> Limited resampling will be performed
>   to help the sample match the
>   initialize arguments for the mixer.

which suggests this kind of problem should solve itself...

But I'll bet this is a sampling frequency problem that can be fixed by either changing the (sampling) frequency of the mixer object to the sampling frequency of your sound files, or resampling your sound files yourself to match the value of the mixer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i used wave.getframerate to determine the sampling frequency of the file and it returns 22050, so i guess it's ok...any ideas?

Comment: @Ant, sorry! I really thought this would be it... you could say I work a lot with audio, but my experience with pygame is limited. I'll get back to you if I have a brainwave :P

Comment: ok, thank you... do you think i need to re-install pygame? the fact i'm on ubuntu may change something? thanks

Comment: have i mentioned i used ubuntu? this would change something?

Answer (score 2):

While I didn't have any luck with adjusting the frequency, setting size=8 and buffer=2048 when calling mixer.init() worked for me.